# allowing values to be used outside of try catch?

Tags: java

The following method id supposed to allow a user to enter a phrase which can then be printed a certain number of times!However, in this method I would like to catch an exception if the user enters a number etc. It seems though that if I insert the try catch where I have then it wont wont let me use the variable "print" in the for loop. any help would be great thanks (I have bolded where the syntax error occurs)

```
public static void printLoop(){
    //Declaring Variables
    int noOfTimes=0;
    String print;

    try{    
        System.out.println("Please enter what you would like to print");
        print=scanner.next();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Please enter valid word/phrase");
        //flush scanner
        scanner.next();
    }
    System.out.println("Please enter how many times you wish to print...");
    noOfTimes=scanner.nextInt();

    for (int counter=0; counter<noOfTimes; counter++){

        System.out.println(print);
    }
}//End of printLoop
```

Comment: You need to initialize `print` variable.

Comment: Why don't you read the error message you get from the compiler? It tells you what the problem is.

Comment: It would be wise to actually read the error message (or at least copy/paste it here so we can read it).  But if you set print to null where you define it that will probably get you past that error.

Comment: Initialize `print` like this `String print = "";` or `String print = null;`

Comment: The problem is that `print` is not initialized along all possible paths, since an exception can occur before you execute `print=scanner.next();`.

Comment: Method local variable `print` must be initialized before using. You will get compilation error `The local variable print may not have been initialized`

Answer (score 0):

If you will not initialize the local variable the complier will not aloow to compile the code always initilize the local variable in your case the print is local variable initialize it like below

`String print="" or String print=null`;

[image]